# Regular expression, grater than, less than, between

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I need to create client side validation for these situations

```
Syntax      Result filter                                     Example
X+          Return all items with X or more                   4+
X-          Return all items with X or less                   10-
X-Y         Return all items between (inclusive) X and Y      4-8
```

Probably the best way is to do something link this

```
function allnumericplusminus(inputtxt) {
var regex = /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/;
if (inputtxt.match(regex)) {
    alert('Correct...Try another');
    return true;
} else {
    alert('Please input correct format');
    return false;
}
}
```

Main problem is because I don't know how to write regular expression for this specific situation.

Can someone help?

Comment: Why cannot you just compare it numerically? What is the reason to use a regular expression here?

Comment: why write a regex? This is easy enough to parse and evaluate desired string in a few lines anyway.

Comment: You are suggest to parse strings and to check values ?

Comment: Use something like `indexOf`, it's not _that_ hard.

Comment: Isn't `\d+` a shortcut for `[0-9]+`?

Comment: regex is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: `return false;` inside both `than` and `else`... makes no sense. Use only once before the  `}` *end*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var regex = /^\-?\d+[\+\-](\-?\d+)?$/;
```

Update:
The regex will pass expressions like "4+8" but they are not needed,so the regex should be this:

```
var regex = /^\-?\d+([\+\-]|(\-\-?\d+)?)$/;
```

Comment: Be careful with this, I think `4+-44` would pass.

Comment: 4+-44?Tested,It's ok.@BillCriswell

Comment: Should that pass, though? `/^\-?\d+[\+\-](\-?\d+)?$/.test('343+-234')` returns true.

Comment: You mean the second number must bigger than the first one?Oh I didn't consider about it,if it's needed, I'll think about it.@BillCriswell

Comment: Oh, duh. You're just taking negative numbers into consideration. My mistake.

Comment: Oh no, @BillCriswell you remind me that "4+8" is not needed according to the example but it would pass,I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function checkIt(text){
  return text.toString().match(/^\d+(+|-)?\d?$/);
}
```